# Add an edit text dropdown in a property grid

Tags: .net, winforms, propertygrid

I am writing a class whose properties are accessed through a property panel, one of these properties is a multiline text.

I want a dropdown to be displayed in the designer of this property panel so that the user fills out a multiline text, the same way a Label or the a TextBox does in Visual Studio.

[image: This is what I want in my property panel]

Which attribute should I put above my property definition to allow this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to decorate the "Text" property with [System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.multilinestringeditor.aspx).

e.g.

```
[Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public string Text { .... }
```

Comment: It's working. Thanks ! I put [Editor(typeof(System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))] so it works with every .net version